Is it possible for a naturally-evolved organism to feed on kinetic energy?
So I was watching a mini-documentary about the Strandbeests of Theo Jansen. I hadn't been paying close attention to his progress with them for a while now, so you can imagine my shock when I learned that he had actually managed to give them muscles that can store the energy of the wind they harness, allowing them to move even without the wind.

He uses pumps powered by their sails to store pressurized air in plastic bottles, which can then be used to power piston-like muscles.
And that got me thinking...
Could a naturally-evolved creature utilize kinetic energy collected from its habitat by converting it into chemical potential energy to be stored for later use?
Let's imagine a creature; a large, herbivorous, warm-blooded quadrupedal creature with a heavy build and a large sail on its back, running along its spine. It lives in a very windy environment, which the creature utilizes by standing parallel to the direction of the wind and letting the wind propel its sail to flap back and forth in a similar motion to a cuttlefish fin (just like the strandbeests). At the base of the sail bones, there is some sort of organ which converts kinetic energy to chemical potential energy. What kind of reaction would have to occur there to make this happen, and what would the structure and biological mechanisms of such an organ be? Is this even possible with our current understanding of molecular biology, and if so, would it at all be an effective method for obtaining energy? And, if you're in an especially fervorous question-answering mood today, how would such a mechanism evolve?

Your biggest problem is that Kinetic energy ir WAY less energy-Dense than chemical energy so to speak. sails work just fine to propel a dead mechanism, but to keep a living creature's metabolism going? even if it was possible, you'd probably need much more wind than this kind of creature could hope to get.

Compare the energy density of a good burger (measured in hundreds of kilojoules/a couple megajoules, easily digestible by humans) to the energy density of a projectile with equivalent kinetic energy (same energy density (roughly), but would incinerate a human). Keep in mind: a kilogram of TNT has a few megajoules of energy in it.

Whilst the above (quite valid) comments likely place it in the "evolutionary dead-end" category, it's an intriguing question. It's one that will likely tick away in the back of my mind for months, if not longer.

The answer is no. Please keep in mind that the goal of worldbuilding is suspension of disbelief, not scientific validity. Personally, I think that a critter that is nourished every time you punch it in the nose is hilarious and a wonderful worldbulding creature.

Teeeeeechnically light is kinetic energy, so plants do this. Not what you've asked for, though, obviously.

Welp. Both of you! Get working on those answers! I'll expect rhino sized chrysanthemums that thrive on being punched by random passers by on my desk by 5pm tomorrow!

@gs Considering light has no mass.... very technically.

VTC:Needs more focus. You're asking six questions (what kind of reaction? What kind of structure? What kind of biological mechanism? Is it possible? Would it be effective? How would it evolve?). Per the [tour], Stack Exchange is not a discussion forum. You're allowed one and only one question per post. Fair warning about the "how would it evolve?" question: that inevitably violates the [help/dont-ask]'s Book Rule (too broad). We barely understand how humans evolved (kinda). That question gets closed regularly unless it's very focused.

Yes, such a mechanism is not only possible, but rather all its component parts are in everyday use.
TL;DR: if there is a source of free energy available then we already know how to use it to make chemistry happen.
Just use the energy of the wind to turn the windmill to turn the generators to make electric power to electrolize water to produce hydrogen to be fed into a Bergius or Fischer–Tropsch process to make synthetic fuel. And that's it: kinetic energy into chemical energy.
And there is no need to speculate as to how such a mechanism would evolve, because it has already evolved. The trick is to have a lineage of little tree-dwelling mammals split from the ancestors of the hares and rabbits; then have the tree-dwelling furries grow and develop opposable thumbs and rudimentary intelligence; then one lineage of primates gives rise to the great apes; then one lineage of great apes is stranded in the savannah and splits from the chimpanzees; then in this lineage of savannah great apes one or more individuals learn to speak, to make fire, and to get organized. And wouldn't you know it, less than 65 million years after their remote ancestors split away from the rabbits and hares you will have several different processes of making liquid fuels from coal and hydrogen using whatever source of free energy is available. Easy peasy.

I resemble that remark...

Hmm, OP asks for an organism, not a mechanism.

Not an answer and not a frame challenge. @AlexP, I have great respect for your wisdom and the practicality you bring to the stack, but this still should have been a comment.

@Vesper: The humans are the organisms, and we are perfectly naturally evolved, just as asked. Our perfectly naturally evolved special shtick is the infinitely flexible ability to augment our bodies to do whatever we want, including the ability to utilize kinetic energy collected from our habitat by converting it into chemical potential energy to be stored for later use, just as required.
